# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() laravel using whereIn (laravel 5.3)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am getting ids using jquery in my controller its as

```
if(!empty($request->input('ids'))) {
    $ids = $request->input('ids');
    }else{
                $ids = null;
            }
```

I try `dd($ids)`

Output is as in my console

```
array:3 [
  0 => "1"
  1 => "2"
  2 => "on"
]
```

When i pass ids to my query as

**Query**

```
$student_ids = DB::table('students')
             ->orderBy('name', 'asc')
              ->where('group_id', '<>', 0)
              ->whereIn('students.id','=', $ids)
              ->pluck('id');
```

Its not working

> Error is : Invalid argument supplied for foreach

Please help where I am wrong. Thanks

Comment: How you get ids in your view? 3. element in array "on" should be there? I think something is wrong there.

Comment: why your id is string there ?

Comment: if($request->has('ids'))) {}

Comment: Where is your foreach actually ?

Comment: ->whereIn('students.id', $ids) - for more info check here https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change this:

```
->whereIn('students.id','=', $ids)
```

To this:

```
->whereIn('students.id', $ids)
```

Because the second parameter should be iterable of IDs, but you're passing a string `=`. Also, make sure, you're passing an array or collection of IDs.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
where('students.id', '=', $ids)
```

To:

```
whereIn('students.id', $ids);
```

Comment: still same issue

Comment: @bluemoon Look closely...you're still using `=` as a 2nd argument to `whereIn`. However, `whereIn` does not accept a comparison operator as the 2nd argument, it only accepts an array as the 2nd argument. Use exactly what I posted above.

Answer (score 1):

Like others have mentioned update the `whereIn` parameter. Also simplify your request input like so.

```
$ids = $request->input('ids', []);

$student_ids = DB::table('students')
    ->orderBy('name', 'asc')
    ->where('group_id', '<>', 0)
    ->whereIn('students.id', $ids)
    ->pluck('id');
```